# how to get the SOAP request value of datamember of datacontract from WCF at AfterReceiveRequest method

Tags: wcf, soap

how to get the SOAP request value of datamember of datacontract  from WCF at AfterReceiveRequest method*/

SOAP Request is

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<s:Header>
<a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://tempuri.org/ITcpService/GetData</a:Action>
<a:MessageID>urn:uuid:fa410c1f-4b74-42e5-998d-565cd5c7b092</a:MessageID>
<a:ReplyTo>
<a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
</a:ReplyTo>
<VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">uIDPoyXtX3m/PSJBo+4Vd2taPwgAAAAAB+2JFplBDU6oJYlfkZ/um28yri7PLBZFmtLNf3F75EMACQAA</VsDebuggerCausalityData>
<a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">net.tcp://localhost/mytcpservice/TcpService.svc</a:To>
</s:Header>
<s:Body>
<GetData xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<value xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/mytcpservice.requests" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<b:Token>0</b:Token>
<b:Data>7</b:Data>
<b:Data2>0</b:Data2>
</value>
</GetData>
 </s:Body>
 </s:Envelope>

public class TestActivation : IDispatchMessageInspector
{
public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel     channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
{
//here fetch Token value if exists
}
}
```

Comment: Doesn't Message request give you access to request data?

Comment: i just want to access request body member instead of header data

Comment: You can get parameters from a message inspector, but its much easier to use a ParameterInspector since it gives you strongly typed CLR values. Is that an option? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iparameterinspector.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can gain access to request data using "request" variable. e.g. You can retrieve header values like user name as follows:

```
public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        var requestHeaders = (HttpRequestMessageProperty)request.Properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name];
        var user = requestHeaders .Headers["Username"];

        //Way to access body. 
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms);
        request.WriteMessage(writer); 
        writer.Flush();
        ms.Position = 0;
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(ms);
        //Now you have xml document object which can be used for further processing
        //Do whatever you want to do here   
        return null;
    }
```